Does the Ptolemy's inequality hold for concave quadrilaterals?
We used a convex quadrilateral to prove that $\overline{AB}\cdot \overline{CD}+\overline{BC}\cdot \overline{DA} \ge \overline{AC}\cdot \overline{BD}$ is true for non-cyclic quadrilaterals. But I was wondering whether this property applies to concave quadrilaterals as well? Because Ptolemy's inequality says that it holds for non-cyclic quadrilaterals1. Which means that this should also apply to concave quadrilaterals, right? So I tried to construct a circle with an inscribed concave quadrilateral.

However, I ran into a problem when I tried to draw the diagonals. It seems like we can't just draw a diagonal from one angle directly to the opposite angle, can we? So does this mean that the Ptolemy's inequality cannot be used on concave quadrilaterals?
1 Ptolemy's inequality

Ptolemy's inequality holds for all quadrilaterals, even concave ones. The diagonals are just $AC$ and $BD$, so I don't understand why "we can't just draw a diagonal from one angle directly to the opposite angle". Maybe you're assuming that the diagonal has to be contained within the quadrilateral?  $\quad$ Note that the quadrilateral isn't allowed to self-intersect.

Yes I thought that we couldn't be able to draw diagonals if they aren't within the quadrilateral. So this means that the diagonals $AC$ and $BC$ doesn't need intersect to be able to use the Ptolemy's inequality?

What do you exactly mean by quadrilateral isn't allowed to self-intersect? Why is this important?

1/ Correct, diagonals AC and BD (minor typo) do not need to intersect.  $\quad$ 2/ Self-intersecting means the there are 2 edges that intersect each other. For example, in the figure $ACBM$ (in that order), the sides AC and BM will intersect, so this figure is self-intersecting. This applies to the definition of a quadrilateral (I mentioned it because you asked for clarification on concave quads) $\quad$ 3/ Note that ptolemy's theorem holds for any 4 points, not just that they must be a quadrilateral. EG They could be 4 points in a line, or they could be the figure $ACBM$.

Thanks for the correction, I did mean $AC$ and $BD$ like you said. $\quad$ 2/ Sorry if I'm misunderstanding this. But if we can use the Ptolemy's inequality for a self-intersecting quadrilateral (like $ACBM$), why did you previously mention that the quadrilateral isn't allowed to have self-intersection? Or did you refer to the quadrilateral $ADCB$? $\quad$ 3/That's very interesting! But how can Ptolemy's inequality be applied if there are no diagonals for the 4 points on a line?

2/ Slight misunderstanding. Two parts to this. Firstly, quadrilaterals by definition are not allowed to self-intersect. Secondly, Ptolemy's inequality applies to any set of 4 points, which includes convex quadrilaterals, convex quadrilaterals, and points on a line. $\quad$ 3/ For any 4 points $A, B, C, D$, we will always have $AB \times CD + AD \times BC \geq AC \times BD$. Furthermore, equality also holds when the points are on a line in that order. EG $a \times c + (a+b+c)\times b = (a+b) \times (b+c)$. A line can be treated as a degenerate circle.

2/ I assume you meant concave quadrilaterals instead of twice convex quadrilaterals? I've seen online that people call this shape a 'crossed quadrilateral'. Is this by any chance also the shape we are talking about? Because this crossed quadrilateral is self-intersecting, why would people call this a quadrilateral? $\quad$ 3/ So how should I know which part of the line should be the diagonal and which the sides? Can we say that the diagonals have the same segment as the sides (the length between the two points)?

2/ Ah yes. It boils down to what definition you use. Typically polygons are not allowed to, though sometimes people call them simple and complex polygons, but it screws things like the angle sums. So you have to take your pick of definition.  $\quad$ 3/ Think of it as just 4 points $A, B, C, D$ and $ AB \times CD + \ldots$. No "diagonal" or "side" involved, just lengths between the points. Check out Casey's theorem, which is generalized Ptolemy's theorem, to see why it's better to think of them as 4 points (which are degenerate circles).

2/ Ohh ok thank you, I didn't know that. So if the definition for poylgons and quadrilaterals is that they don't self-intersect. Does this mean that the term crossed quadrilateral is actually wrong? I'm a bit confused what is correctly now. $\quad$ 3/ Thank you for sharing, I'll check that out. So if I understand it correctly, if we have the points (degenerate circles) $A, B, C, D$ on a horizontal line. We can say that $AB \times CD + AD \times BC \geq AC \times BD$? So I should think of them as segments with length instead of actually diagonals and sides?

2/ Like I said, it depends on what definition you use. Typically we go with simple quad (EG So that sum of interior angles is $360^\circ$.) But as things get more advanced, they might want to modify the definition.  $\quad$ 3/ Correct, think of them as segments with lengths. The "diagonal" part is mainly helpful to remember what is on the RHS, but since these points are interchanagable, all version of the inequality are true (that the sum of any 2 products is greater than the third).

2/ Ohhh ok, I think I understand what you mean. So, the term crossed quadrilateral is typically used for those who are just starting to explore mathematical concepts. As we delve deeper, we might consider changing the definition. Does this mean that if we wanted to be precise, we shouldn't use 'crossed quad' and should say that polygons, including quads, should not be self-intersecting? Do I understand this correctly? $\quad$ 3/ Ohh wow this concept seems so powerful. Thank you for your help.

2/ It depends on the context and what you're studying. EG If you're familiar with directed angles, the the angle sum makes sense again.

2/ Aha ok understood. I want to thank you for your help these last few days! I really appreciate your patience, especially in answering my questions one after another (which doesn't always happen with others). And again, thank you. I've learned alot from you.
